# How a make Installer in TFSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, installation

Can you please help me in making installers in TFS build.

Tools Used:

1. Visual studio 2010
2. TFS 2010
3. Visual Studio installer.

Requirement:

1. Need to make installers for multiple web applications which are part of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Jehan33's answer should get you up and running however you should be aware that MS are [retiring the Visual Studio Installer](https://msmvps.com/blogs/installsite/archive/2010/09/23/microsoft-will-retire-visual-studio-installer.aspx), I'd suggest using [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the installer for web application project by using Visual Studio Web Setup Project template.To build this setup projects from Team Build, you can check this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/05/14/building-visual-studio-setup-projects-with-tfs-2010-team-build.aspx).